# navbar toggle button shifts right on click

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i have a bootstrap navbar on m webpage and it has a toggle button which is on right side. But when i click on it, it shifts right by 10px and then when it collapses, it shifts back. This looks weird. I tried margin: 0 auto !important; in css. But this makes toggle button's position center. I want my toggle button to appear on right and should not move on click.

I have added so many h3 tags in between navbar-brand and toggle button to make toggle button appear right. Because it was not appearing otherwise.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top navbar-collapse" style="position: fixed;">
        <!--<a class="navbar-brand text-center w-100" href="#">Navbar</a>-->
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" height="50px" width="60px" style="align:center; position: fixed !important;"></a>

        
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler navbar-right ml-auto" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link active" style=" text-align: center;" ><h4><b>HOME</b></h4></a>
                <a href="buy.html" class="nav-link button" style="text-align: center;"><h4><b>OPPURTUNITIES</b></h4></a>
                <a href="advertise.html" class="nav-item nav-link" style=" text-align: center;"><h4><b>BECOME PARTNER</b></h4></a>
                <a href="other.html" class="nav-item nav-link" style=" text-align: center;"><h4><b>OTHER PRODUCTS</b></h4></a>
                <a href="#contactform" class="nav-item nav-link" style="text-align: center;"><h4><b>CONTACT</b></h4></a>
               <div class="nav-link" style="text-align: center;"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pratham.notebook" ><i class="fab fa-facebook-square" ></i></a>
                &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="https://www.instagram.com/pratham.notebook"><i class="fab fa-instagram" ></i></a>
            </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this class CSS into your code.

```
 button.navbar-toggler {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. However i solved the issue by adding class ml-auto in my navbar-toggler.